# Change the gray app background color

Tags: themes, gtk, colors

A lot of apps have this gray color background. I would like to change the color.  I'm using a window manager without a desktop environment (`$DESKTOP_SESSION` is empty).

Where is the color determined and how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the application. Two common frameworks are used for a lot of apps: Qt and Gtk. They each have several versions and each version gets its own settings.

Evince uses Gtk-3, so I needed to download and extract a Gtk-3.0 theme into `~/.themes` and set `gtk-theme-name = Mojave-dark` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`.

There's a similar story for Qt apps like Okular. Some themes have been ported to both frameworks, so you can [get a consistent look](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications) by downloading the same theme for both.

You can find out which framework an app uses by looking at the apps's dependencies. For example, `apt-cache depends evince` shows (among other things), `Depends: libgtk-3-0`.

More info - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=940041